# making a for loop reset itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop, gif

new to writing javascript/jquery.

I'm taking video/gif scrubber (https://github.com/ghepting/javascript-video-scrubber) and I want it to be able to continuously loop the background image gif. Is there an easy way to make a for loop reset itself so when it reaches the last image it'll go back to the first image?

```
for(i = 0; i < totalFrames; i++) { // loop for each image in sequence
        images[i] =  new Image(); // add image object to array
        images[i].src = "./frames/frame_"+pad(i, 2)+"_delay-0.04s.gif"; // set the source of the image object
    }
```

Comment: yes, but you don't want to do that as it will stop any other javascript from running

Comment: You probably want to use `setInterval()` (a recurring timer) and change the image every nn ms).  See [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) for `setInterval()`.  You then increase a counter in the timer function and when it reaches the limit, you set the counter back to `0`.

Comment: The remainder operator `%` works the same as _modulo_ for positive numbers, e.g. `0 % 3 === 0`, `1 % 3 === 1`, `2 % 3 === 2`, `3 % 3 === 0`, `4 % 3 === 1`, etc, i.e. `n * x + y` `%` `x` `===` `y`